# File in docker volume not updating

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, docker-volume, docker-container

Hi I have a Nifi docker container stopped and I want to update a property file.
Whenever I update a field, when I run docker-compose start it doesn't update  the property file.
How can this be possible?
here is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Thanks

Comment: normally you do not need also to stop/start to update the file that should be done on the fly....

Comment: try to   cat /home/ubuntu/nifi/conf and docker exec nifi cat /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf  , if they're both showing the same un-updated data, it could be that your application writes to the config file when its started

Comment: It changes in both on a running container. However I do need restart it because Nifi reads this properties on start and the mod disappears. How could I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue a while back as well. I believe using volumes essentially creates a symlink, and when the container starts up it overwrites anything in that folder.

Have you considered creating a multistage build? That was our solution:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM apache/nifi:1.9.2
ADD /path/to/your-props.properties /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
```

We then put the resulting image in our compose

Comment: I thought this could be the problem. I'll try out this solution and let know. thanks